# Renaming Files with Similar Filenames to the Same Filename but Different Folder

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

I have a lot of files in subsubfolders. They all look like in.*.radiate, where * is just a number. I need to rename these similar filenames in the different subfolder to a constant name, but keep them in their respective folders.

Is there a way to rename all of them with a single command to just in.radiate?

Either in linux or MATLAB?

Perl script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $newname = 'in.radiate'; # If you want a different filename, edit this line

foreach my $folder (glob("*"))
{
    # Ensure it's a folder
    if (-d $folder)
    {
        print "Processing $folder\n";
        system("mv $folder/*.radiate $folder/$newname");
    }
}
```

Comment: But you can't rename two files to the same thing if they're in the same directory. Are they all in their own directories?

Comment: Do they have headers? Also you have multiple subfolders with many files in each one of them. Is that correct?

Comment: Why not import them, store their data into the workspace, and re-save the workspace?

Comment: OK I am in Parent directory. Then in parent directory, there are 24 subdirectories. In each of these, there are 150 subdirectories,each with a file named in.*.radiate. I want to change all of these to in.radiate. They are in their own folders

Answer (score 1):

A bash solution:

```
for file in $(find dir -iname "*.radiate"); do
mv $file ${file/.*././}
done
```

To find all your .radiate files:

```
$ find dir -iname "*.radiate"
dir-root/1/1/in.1.radiate
dir-root/1/10/in.10.radiate
dir-root/1/100/in.100.radiate
dir-root/1/101/in.101.radiate
dir-root/1/102/in.102.radiate
...
```

After replacing all .*. with . using above for loop:

```
$ find dir -iname "*.radiate"
dir-root/1/1/in.radiate
dir-root/1/10/in.radiate
dir-root/1/100/in.radiate
dir-root/1/101/in.radiate
dir-root/1/102/in.radiate
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible in MATLAB. the [movefile](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html?refresh=true) function allows you to move a file to the same folder it is in and give it a new name. You'll want to generate a list of all the files including paths and then loop through each one. something like below..

```
    %found_files represents the results of the search function i will 
    %mention below.
    new_name= 'in.radiate';

    for pp = 1 : length(found_files)

        %create string of path with new file name
        renamed_file = strcat(path, new_name); 

        %move file command. 
        movefile(found_files(pp).name, renamed_file);

    end
```

in order to get a full list of all the files I would using something like this function on [matlab exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/19550-recursive-directory-listing). it will generate a struct with all files according to a specific filter which for you could be 'radiate'.

Comment: Took a quick skim and it looks okay. Just to confirm, it keeps the files in the same folder right?

Comment: The file on matlab exchange just generates a list of paths among some other info like file file size and date... you then do all the moving with your loop. you will need to tweak the code for the loop i provided.. maybe set-up a small sample to test on.

Comment: I edited my question. Do you know If there is a way in linux to do this as well? It's working for subfolders but not subsubfolders (check my code in post)

Comment: I'm afraid i'm not your guy when it comes to perl. I'd assume it is possible... rsync could potentially make a second copy with the same file structure as the original but with the files re-named. but i can't be 100% about that.

Comment: @Jack i just realised you might have been asking about the loop. with movefile if you for the inputs the files have the same path but different names then it will behave like a rename as opposed to an actual move. the docs explain and show an example.